# What does "dividend" mean in the context of betting?

Tags: terminology, betting, horse-racing

For example:

> **Tote** - The organisation appointed to receive bets and supply ***dividends*** in proportion to the amount of the investment. A body in the UK set up to operate pool-betting on all racecourses.

Answer (score 3):

The **dividend** is:

> The amount that a winning or placed horse returns for every $1 bet by the bettor<sub>[(1)](http://horsebettingpicks.net/glossary/#d)</sub> <sub>[(2)](http://www.offtrackbetting.com/horse-racing-terms.html)</sub> <sub>[(3)](http://www.ildado.com/horse_racing_glossary.html)</sub>:

So, in your example, a Tote would distribute returns to applicable bettors.